# Signing using BouncyCastle in .NET and verifying in NodeJS

Tags: .net, node.js, rsa, bouncycastle, sign

**What I have:**
 A .Net client application and a Nodejs Server application.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**.Net Client application signs the request data using a client private key and the signature should be verified at the server using client public key.

**The Problem:** Verification always fails.

**Client Code (Using BouncyCastle):**

```
        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding(); 
        var inputData = encoder.GetBytes(plainText);

        var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256WITHRSA"); 
        signer.Init(true, privateKey); 
        signer.BlockUpdate(inputData, 0, inputData.Length); 

        var sign = signer.GenerateSignature(); 
        var signmsg = Convert.ToBase64String(sign);  //This signature is sent to server
```

**Server Code using ('ursa'):**

```
      var isauthentic=pubkeyClient.hashAndVerify('sha256', plainText, signmsg, 'base64');  
    // this is always false. plainText is the same request message in the
    // client and signmsg is the signature sent by the client
```

**Server Code using ('node-rsa'):**

```
      var b = new Buffer(signmsg, 'base64');
      var auth=pubkeyClient.verify(plainText, b); // This returns false too
```

EDIT: Added code which uses the node-rsa module. The result is pretty much the same.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. I tested with the following C# code and node's (tested with node v5.10.0) built-in `crypto` module:

**C#:**

```c#
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var plainText = "Hello world";
        var privatePEM = @"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

        PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(privatePEM));
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();

        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding(); 
        var inputData = encoder.GetBytes(plainText);

        var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256WITHRSA"); 
        signer.Init(true, keys.Private);
        signer.BlockUpdate(inputData, 0, inputData.Length); 

        var sign = signer.GenerateSignature(); 
        var signmsg = Convert.ToBase64String(sign);
        Console.WriteLine(signmsg);
    }
}
```

**node.js:**

```javascript
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

// `signmsg` displayed by the above C# program
var sig = 'ivMHsoMoXc61wcJpvelTonBkd5fqDD+aNJpo0DiamisAT5uXiTcGm56C+MIc5dd+ELTG54YRb2MzETRnBlsh6Tm9fHbCwSdZJ0GxqnKb56VKZvccQ+740Q3vw7GYfspidyUuonOA+tDLc73fhSRfTlG7c4EuzZzUvMy+2epMA7HC2drWmMXARhY1jeAPz3ofUX7$

// Public key derived from `privatePEM` in the above C# program
var pubKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwTOUkBeDyeEiacGyW5Uw
NCg73GuIMaUNMXZwnCSjQYpMqxzrq3UdwFxM9Ln6rXCDJgUALvrbI6TK6HwKG/EP
bC277IWvJ0WbqGpn47th70JMFyssLqNEREot3H9CFCmn7SM8jjQOYAQ+4M5BqPEd
6gwprtP+/GxZ0nP46vSrA7qlyyp2MO2yTovWH5QfYB1bQvjAChEydqAP1Alqo5i2
QnZ50FD6QFr2KG3+f7xmvL3K/gSs+ayjDNYjrKoJwY6xJ/U4103Xddr5zP0g6WL+
zyjTW9M0CCXsQ7wCrPWxEXmVQeg7BbSwx6ATbP2pbuWHfp2GrO6PIw2wMzOwNa/O
0QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

var verify = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verify.update('Hello world');
console.log(verify.verify(pubKey, new Buffer(sig, 'base64')));
// Outputs:
// true
```

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to narrow down the problem. The problem is that the plainText variable in the client application is a JSON string generated using JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);. This adds '/' in between which causes the string at the client and the server to differ, thus causing the verification to fail all the time.Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: What is `data` in that case? I've never seen a JSON serializer randomly add a slash in the serialized output.

Comment: `data` in this is case is an object which is serialized into a JSON object using `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);`. This JSON string is encrypted and sent to the server. The server decrypts the message and gets a visually similar JSON string. But there is some difference I can't figure out. This is what is causing the problem for me. Instead of the JSON string, if I use a simple string like "Hello World" like you did, this works perfectly fine. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I'm not able to test specifically with `JavaScriptSerializer()` because I don't have access to an actual Windows machine, but using [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) for example generates valid JSON with [a simple test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LHb9ig) that serializes a `Hashtable`.

Comment: It was working fine with strings, but when using files (`var fs = require('fs')`) - I had to *remove* the encoding specifier - from `fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')` to `fs.readFileSync(filename)`

Comment: After several days of trial and error (signing in C# and verifying in node.js), I finally settled on this solution. Thanks so much for this. I really appreciate it.